# how to read data from socket in android

Tags: android, sockets

I want to Connect my android application with RN171.

Here is my code:

```
try{


InetAddress modemAddr = InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4");
        Socket socket = new Socket(modemAddr, 2000);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println("$$$");
        out.println("get everything");
        socket.close();
        InetAddress modemAddr2 = InetAddress.getByName("1.2.3.4");
        Socket socket2 = new Socket(modemAddr2, 2000);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket2.getInputStream()));
        String inMsg = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
         builder.setTitle("Response");// Set the Title of Alert Dialog
         builder.setMessage(total.toString())
         .setPositiveButton("OK",dialogClickListener).show();
        }
 socket2.close();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  builder.setTitle("Response");// Set the Title of Alert Dialog
                 builder.setMessage(e.toString())
                 .setPositiveButton("OK",dialogClickListener).show();
}
```

I am sending `get everything` command to RN171 and want to alert its output.

But app runs for sometime and message appears that app is not responding.

How can i do this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893911/android-client-socket-how-to-read-data

Comment: Are you running this within an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`, or are you doing at some other place?

Comment: i am doing this in oncreate method in main activity only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading the input until end of stream, and not doing anything until you get it. Unless the device disconnects, you will therefore block forever. You need to process each piece of data as you get it.

Comment: you mean i should close the write socket after writting data and open it again for reading?

Comment: can you please give some detail, may be example, i am newbie in android

Comment: I said nothing of the sort. I meant what I said. Look again. 'Process each piece of data as you get it' seems clear to me.

Comment: okey, i should alert each line separately not at the end, i guess that's what you mean

Comment: It's what I *said.* No guesswork required. It really baffles me why people play guessing games about what someone means, when they already have the text of what they actually said sitting right in front of them.

Comment: have try that also but its the same result

Comment: Tried it how? Show the code. And I don't mean to put it illegibly into a comment. Edit it into your question.