# Client only socket programming in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, tcp

I would like to open a TCP connection to send data to an ip address in an android application. Every socket programming article/thread I find shows both client and server side code (often the chat program). Is it possible to just have the client code running on an android device and send arbitrary data to, for example, google's IP address? Right now I am using the code from this thread (highest upvoted answer) [Android Client socket , how to read data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893911/android-client-socket-how-to-read-data) in a class that extends AsynchTask like this:

```
public class InternetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    private Socket socket = null;
    private PrintWriter out = null;
    private BufferedReader in = null;
    private int port = 80;
    private String host = null;
    private static final String TAG="sure2015test";

    public InternetTask(String host,int port) {
        this.host=host;
        this.port=port;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {


        connectWithServer();
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
        sendDataWithString("hello");
        Log.i(TAG, "Sent data");
        String response=receiveDataFromServer();
        Log.i(TAG,response);
        disConnectWithServer();
        return null;
    }


    private void connectWithServer() {
        try {
            if (socket == null) {
                socket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"IO Exeception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void disConnectWithServer() {
        if (socket != null) {
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG,"IO exception disconnecting");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendDataWithString(String message) {
        if (message != null) {
            connectWithServer();
            out.write(message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public String receiveDataFromServer() {
        try {
            String message = "";
            int charsRead = 0;
            char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            Log.i(TAG,"Message before: "+message);
            while ((charsRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                message += new String(buffer).substring(0, charsRead);
                Log.i(TAG,message);
            }
            Log.i(TAG,"Message after: "+message);
            disConnectWithServer(); // disconnect server
            return message;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG,"IO Error in receiving message");
            return "Error receiving response:  " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And my onCreate method in MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    InternetTask task=new InternetTask("74.125.226.159",80);
    task.execute();
}
```

When I run this I get this in the logs:

```
05-16 00:01:04.368      622-637/? I/sure2015test﹕ Connected
05-16 00:01:04.369      622-637/? I/sure2015test﹕ Sent data
05-16 00:01:04.369      622-637/? I/sure2015test﹕ Message before:
05-16 00:03:04.405      622-637/com.example.connorstein.sockethelloworld I/sure2015test﹕ Message after:
```

So there were no exceptions when opening a socket on port 80 with the IP of google and no exceptions sending or receiving the data. It looks like I just have no response. Is this expected because the data I sent ("hello") is meaningless? I would think that at least I would get a response saying invalid request or something like that. I also tried sending "GET / HTTP/1.0", but also no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is responding blank because you aren't sending it a proper HTTP request. Mimic the request of a normal web browser, and you will get a response. HTTP is a protocol built on top of TCP. You need to follow the protocol to get anything useful out of servers.

Example minimal browser header that gets a response:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.37.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n
```

Instead of using a web server, consider using an SSH server. An SSH server will send something like...

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3\r\n
```

...when you connect. A server that always responds is a lot easier to troubleshoot client code. Note that you might make a sysadmin mad constantly connecting to their ssh server. You may want to set up your own to test against.

Comment: I still get a blank response with your GET request

Comment: Nevermind my cut and paste of the request didn't work properly. It works! I just needed the \r\n\r\n. Thanks a lot.